# Codeigniter using input datepicker cannot post to database

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using a Codeigniter script purchased in Codecanyon. I need add the input datepicker but in Controller cannot get from UI picked date.

UI:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control datetimepicker"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" name="deadline" id="deadline">
```

Controller :

```
$deadline =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post('deadline')));
```

I have test to show before update database but it's display current time:

```
var_dump($deadline);
return;
```

Comment: is your datetimepicker is working fine?

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($deadline); ?

Comment: 1./ picker workfine but controller cannot get it https://imgur.com/I6XNMZK

2./  var_dump is display https://imgur.com/xdX91RZ

Comment: Try this <input type="date" class="form-control datetimepicker"  name="deadline" id="deadline">
$deadline =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post('deadline')));

Comment: Hi Danish Ali, Thanks you for support. I try this to result : string(10) "1970-01-01"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal you're dealing with is outside the form. I made it that - using jquery - when the date field is changed, it updates the value of its hidden field which is in the form. So when the modal triggers form submission, the value of its date field is also submitted to the controller.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="deadline" id="deadlinehidden" value="" />
```

**JS:**

```
$("#deadline").on("change paste keyup", function() {
    $("#pos-sale-form input[name='deadline']").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Blue, thanks you for support .
I try this to result "1970-01-01 00:00:00" .

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: i try it : https://imgur.com/a/YYJAVoM - to result is time now https://imgur.com/ckVG1ZK

Comment: $_POST['deadline'] is empty, can you post the whole form code?

Comment: yes, UI code : https://notepad.pw/01y25l6s - date picker in line 786 | Controller code :  https://notepad.pw/uy5f2se1 - in line 60 . You can copy code to anther tools

Comment: You're date picker plugin is attached to the wrong class - `$('.datepicker')` - use - `.datetimepicker` - instead of `.datepicker`

Comment: i trying, still not work. On script datepicker change to datetimepicker -> Cannot pick on UI - datetimepicker

Comment: Try this one: https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1qh5fud0aqzxGnyQ6H8wpiE3qAm7pg6Gc&export=download

Comment: Good. Fixed. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<input name="deadline" type="text" value="2017-07-08" class="form-control datepicker" id="datepicker">

 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

$date=$this->input->post('deadline');
```